# Some positive Maclaurin series related to $\cos$ and $\sin$ functions

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

Consider the known inequality
$$1 - \cos x \ge 0$$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. This is because the expression equals $2 \sin^2 \frac{x}{2}\ge 0$. Using the power series expression for $\cos x$, the inequality is equivalent to
$$\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^4}{4!} + \frac{x^6}{6!} -\cdots = \sum_{n\ge 1} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\ge 0$$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with equality if and only if $x=2k \pi$, $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Integrating from $0$ to a limit $x$ we get more inequalities
$$\frac{x^3}{3!} - \frac{x^5}{5!} + \frac{x^7}{7!} - \cdots$$
$$\frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^6}{6!} + \frac{x^8}{8!} - \cdots$$
$$\ldots $$
the ones with odd exponents valid for $x\ge 0$, the other for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Moreover, we have equalities only for $x = 0$. We can rewrite the inequalities as follow:

$$1 \ge \cos x$$
$$x \ge \sin x$$
$$1 - \frac{x^2}{2} \le \cos x$$
$$x - \frac{x^3}{3!} \le \sin x$$
$$\ldots $$

Now, the interesting thing is the following: take one of the inequalities above and divide the smaller by the larger term. We get a series of form $1 - $ a positive series. The only exception is for $\frac{\cos x}{1}$ and $\frac{\sin x}{x}$, where the inverse is still positive ( well known). An example

$$\frac{1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^6}{6!}}{\cos x} = 1 - \frac{x^8}{40320} - \frac{11 x^{10}}{907200} - \frac{241 x^{12}}{47900160} - \frac{44567 x^{14}}{21794572800} - \frac{17345443 x^{16}}{20922789888000}-\cdots
$$

So this inequality for small enough $|x|$ implies $1 - \frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^4}{4!} - \frac{x^6}{6!}\le \cos x$, that we already knew.

I wonder if there would be a proof for the above statements.  Thank you for your interest!